# eigen_msg.h not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can locate eigen_msg.h at

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/eigen_conversions/include/eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h
```

but when I #include eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h in my code I get the following error.

```
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/map_info.dir/src/node_map.o
/home/khan/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/lawn_mover/src/node_map.cpp:2:41: fatal error: eigen_conversions/eigen_msg.h: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59758/eigen_msg.h-not-found/) by [Mudassir Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4582/mudassir-khan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are likely missing the correct xml tags defining which packages you are depending on.

In Fuerte, your `manifest.xml` needs

```
<depend package="eigen_conversions" />
```

In Groovy, your `package.xml` needs

```
<build_depend package="eigen_conversions />
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3